# Datagridview jumbled/overlapping text and random rubbish appearing

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Hello to all you lovely people reading this!

I have an unbound DatagridView on a form and it keeps on getting its contents jumbled/overlapped. There's no paint overriding, fewer than 20 rows and there's only text going into the cells. The problem appears when I switch tabs to the one with the form on it and also sometimes when I hide rows. When switching tabs I get a small imprint of text from the old tab stick onto the datagridview.
I've tried putting refreshes everywhere but that didn't help.

The jumbling after hiding rows looks similar to this guys problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296390/datagridview-jumbled-text-rendering-and-setting-backcolor

Please, any help you can give would be much appreciated. I'm on a strict and very close deadline!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have had similiar issues with DataGridViews when some of the cell styles I was using contained Transparent colors.

Try checking you cell styles and changing any transparent colors to a non-transparent color.

That resolved my particular issues anyway.

Comment: You sir are a genius! This problem was driving me mad but removing Transparent colours does indeed seem to fix the problem.

Comment: but I want to use transparent background color